# If $\int f(z) dz = 0$ for every closed triangular region $T ⊂ U$. Show that $f$ is holomorphic on $U$

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: Question]

I don't think I am fully understanding this question. How can you show that it is holomorphic?

Comment: See [Morera's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem).